# Sitecore download media button injecting surplus HTML markup

Tags: .net, sitecore, sitecore8

**Context**

- Running Sitecore CMS 8.2 rev. 161115 (Update-1)

**Problem**

See screen shot below. When I click "Download", the file is download but has appended to the content 3 html meta tags. `*FILE CONTENTS*` is a place holder for this example, but could be any content (text, image binary, etc).

```
*FILE CONTENTS*<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/default/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="/sitecore/shell/controls/Lib/Flexie/flex.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

*However*, when I click "View file" the file button in the sitecore media control, the file is opened up as a raw file in the browser, and the 3 html meta tags are not present, the file displays as expected.

Further, pressing download **on any media item directly** in Sitecore CMS has the same problem.

For some further information, string searching for `flex.css` led us to this file - `sitecore\shell\Controls\Error.htm`.

However the contents of this file (trimmed just to show link tags is)

```
...
<link href="/sitecore/shell/Themes/Standard/Default/Default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/sitecore/shell/Themes/Standard/Default/Dialogs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/sitecore/shell/Controls/Lib/Flexie/flex.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
```

You'll notice that `Dialogs.css` is not present in our issue, so I don't think it's this file. But including this information in case it helps others thought process in what might be causing this.

**Question**

Has anybody had this before and knows why this is happening?

**Screenshots**

[image: The Sitecore control displayed for the File field.]

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore has released a patch for that please apply that patch to fix this issue. You can find all information @ https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.90534/releases/

Comment: The link is not working anymore. Could you please share the fix directly?

Answer (score 0):

Although patching approach cannot compete with using latest platform versions [7.2 - 8.2 patch is here](https://sitecore.box.com/s/gkhs8sr76h5m73f190bizv4ixxc5rbgs) & [8.2 Initial - Update 2 patch is here](https://sitecore.box.com/s/sq2fbrfijxpl0qbvavop7amevl4vqhpr).

We invest tons of efforts into making the upgrade process easy & making each version better.

Why not spend the time on upgrading instead of tackling bugs in legacy software versions?